# Problem with hyperref / cleveref / thmtools

Tags: hyperref, warnings, cleveref, thmtools

The following is a (fairly) minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\itshape, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\itshape,
postheadspace=1em
]{mystyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, parent=section, style=mystyle,
refname={Theorem,Theorems},
Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[name=Proposition, sibling=theorem, style=mystyle,
refname={Proposition,Propositions},
Refname={Proposition,Propositions}]{prop}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = blue,
urlcolor = magenta,
citecolor = red,
pdfpagemode = UseNone,
pdfpagelayout = SinglePage,
pdfdisplaydoctitle = true,
plainpages = false}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}\label[prop]{prop:112}

Testing this out!
\end{prop}

\begin{prop}\label[prop]{prop:113}
Still Testing!
\end{prop}

\cref{prop:112} and \cref{prop:113}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that both links point to the first proposition.  I also get the error

> `destination with the same identifier (name{prop.\\theHprop\040}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`.

Does anyone know what steps I need to take to resolve this problem (I thought I had already done enough!).  Perhaps it is pertinent, but I also get the error

> `Package thmtools warning: Your version of cleveref is too old!`

but I just updated both packages!

Comment: Do you actually need cleverref? I mean, does hyperref's `autoref` not work for you?

Comment: you might have to do something like `\newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{proposition}` to make it work (I can't remember exactly how hyperref's autoref works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works properly for me. (No log file messages from thmtools). Package versions

```
hyperref.sty    2010/09/13 v6.81n Hypertext links for LaTeX
cleveref.sty    2010/09/04 v0.17.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
thmtools.sty    2010/08/09 v50
```

Comment: the links both link to the appropriate proposition?

Comment: @Steve D: Yes, see http://drop.io/6tlpvro

Comment: @Lev Bishop: OK, I am no longer getting the thmtools warning.  But I am still getting the duplicate warning, and the links are still not working.  I am relatively new at this.  Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe a very silly thing. But have you tried removing all `.aux` files before compiling again?

Comment: @Juan: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, still getting the duplicate error.  Is there a way I can get version numbers, etc., for all the packages I'm using, if that would be helpful?

Comment: You can get version numbers by putting `\listfiles` as the first line of your document. The version numbers are listed in the log file.

Comment: OK I got a hyperref version of 2008/11/18 v6.78m, but I just installed the newest version?

Comment: Alright, well after fighting this for a while, I finally just switched to TeXLive 2010, and it works like a charm.  Thanks for everyone who helped out!