# Issue with thmtools and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, thmtools

I have seen other issues about cleveref and thmtools ([A problem with thmtools and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49937/a-problem-with-thmtools-and-cleveref), [Problem with hyperref / cleveref / thmtools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/problem-with-hyperref-cleveref-thmtools),  [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25047/how-do-i-get-rid-of-particular-pdftex-warning-message)), but they are not exactly like mine.

**What I have done:**
I use both packages in a book environment, I defined theorem and lemma (with numberline=theorem) environments using thmtool and I define one lemma in the first chapter and a second one in the second chapter. I use `\ref` or `\cref` to cite the second lemma.

**What I get**:
I have the following warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{lemma.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

and in practice, the right label is showed in the pdf, but the hyperlink links with the first lemma.

*Any ideas on how to fix it ?*

Here's a MWE:

```
%!TEX encoding =UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{book}

%%%============== Packages
% \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Permet de gerer les accents en francais
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


% \usepackage{amsthm}
% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
% \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,name=Theorem,
  refname={theorem,theorems},
  Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theorem,name=Lemma,
refname={lemma,lemmas},
Refname={Lemma,Lemmas}]{lemma}


% Creation de liens hypertextes (cliquables)
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Creation de liens hypertextes (cliquables)
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\title{Packages clash}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Section 1 1}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem:1}
    Lemma 1
\end{lemma}


\chapter{Second}
\section{Section 2 1}


\begin{lemma}\label{lem:2}
    Lemma 2

\end{lemma}

\section{Section 2 2}


\ref{lem:2}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the `\declaretheorem` statements *after* loading `cleveref`. Everything else about your setup is fine.

```
...
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,name=Theorem,
  refname={theorem,theorems},
  Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theorem,name=Lemma,
  refname={lemma,lemmas},
  Refname={Lemma,Lemmas}]{lemma}
...
```

Do note, though, that the `capitalise` option of the `cleveref` package will have no effect for `\cref`-type cross-references to `theorem` and `lemma` environments: the values set via the `refname` options in the `\declaretheorem` statements override the work of the `capitalise` option.

Comment: Good to know thank you. Actually I had another issue with using just `amsthm` and `cleveref` (it did not recognise `lemma`), and the solution was the same and documented in 14.1 of the documentation. May be another "non-bugs" about mathtool could be added to the section, I will ask the maintainer.

Comment: @PierreMarchand - Indeed, while `cleveref` is quite cunning at figuring out various things, it does need to have been loaded by the time `\declaretheorem` (in case of `thmtools` package) or `\newtheorem` (in the case of `amsthm`) statements are executed. Interestingly, if the `ntheorem` package is employed, it is not strictly necessary to have loaded `cleveref` before various `\newtheorem` directives are executed.