# Adding `UsedOn` option to cleveref's \cref to mimic hyperref's \backcite

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, expl3, cleveref, back-referencing

(This question and answer led to the new package `cleveref-usedon`, see the [CTAN version](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref-usedon) or the [dev version](https://github.com/SvenPistre/cleveref-usedon) on github.)

I am trying to overload `\label` and `\cref`, so that the following happens (similar in spirit to `backref`'s `\backcite`):

- In some preliminary chapter, I define in Theorem A a label `\label{thm:A}`.
- Later in the main text I am referencing Theorem A via `\cref{thm:A}`.
- Retrospectively, I would like the reader of the prelim chapter to know where the result will be used later on in the main text by letting the header of Theorem A be followed by a "Used on page XYZ." phrase.

I have tried the following which works when the label is only referenced once.
Basically, I create a command `\crefusedon` which in turn defines a label which adds a prefix `backref:` to the original labelname, e.g. `backref:thm:A`. The label command is overloaded to search for the existence of `backref:LABELNAME` and print the text above. The `\cref` command is overloaded to include `\crefusedon`. This way I only have to manually add the option [usedon] to all the `\cref`'s in my main text which need it and the rest work as before.

**Problem(s):**

- The downside of this is that it currently only works for one (or rather the last) call of `\crefusedon`. Of course, it would be much better to actually take note of all `\crefusedon` calls and have a phrase such as "Used on pages X, Y and Z." if there multiple calls. Can I use `backref` for this?
- I can `\RenewDocumentCommand` `\label` but for some reason not `\cref`. Any idea why?
- Somewhat confusingly the hyperlink in the `\cpageref` does not link to the correct page in this MWE. However, in my normal document the `\cpageref` hyperlink works but sometimes the opposite `\crefusedon` hyperlink points to a (very) wrong page.

I'm guessing I can somehow use or modify `\backcite` to do what I want but I've had trouble understanding `backref`'s and `cleveref`'s codebase.
What's a sensible solution to this? If backref can do this, I'm happy to scrap the below half-solution.
Btw, I am using biblatex in my normal document and know that there might be a problem with backref in that case.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}             %AMS theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}           %better theorem editing interface
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%=========================================
% -------- Exceptions to Hyperref (load last) ----------
%=========================================
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}               % needs to be loaded AFTER hyperref
                                                % to not conflict with hyperref's \autoref

%=========================================
% -------- BEGIN Overload label and cref ----------
%=========================================
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\usedon}{ m }{%
    % Check if the label `backref:<LABELNAME>` exists
    \ifcsdef{r@backref:#1}{%
        \emph{(Used on \cpageref{backref:#1}.)}%
        \\%
    }{}
}%
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\origlabel\label
    \let\origcref\cref
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{ m }{%
        \origlabel{#1}\usedon{#1}%
    }%
    \NewDocumentCommand{\crefusedon}{ s o m }{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%      
            \origcref*{#3}
        }{%
            \origcref{#3}
        }%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{usedon}{%
            % \cref can also get a list of labels as input, loop through them
            \foreach \x in {#3}{
                \label{backref:\x}%
            }%
        }{}%
    }%
    \let\cref\crefusedon
}%
%=========================================
% -------- END Overload label and cref ----------
%=========================================

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to wonders}
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:egregium}
This is a great theorem about wonderful mathematics.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:inconspicuam}
A plane is flat.
\end{theorem}

\clearpage
As seen in \cref[usedon]{thm:egregium} the earth is positively curved
and according to \cref{thm:inconspicuam} flat earth is not.

\clearpage
As seen in \cref[usedon]{thm:egregium} the earth is positively curved
and according to \cref{thm:inconspicuam} flat earth is not.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For problem 3 above: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498242/267438).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This question and answer led to the new package `cleveref-usedon`, see the [CTAN version](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref-usedon) or the [dev version](https://github.com/SvenPistre/cleveref-usedon) on github.)

I'm not sure this is a useful feature for anyone but me and potentially using a package such as `\zref` might be better suited.
In any case, this has prompted me to learn and implement a solution with `expl3`. Comments on anything wrong with my `expl3` code are welcome.
Run `pdflatex` twice to see the result.
I've used the bugfix from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603514/267438) to repair `cleveref`'s problem for ranges when calling `\cpageref` with multiple arguments.

The commands `\cref`, `\Cref` and `\label` retain their normal behaviour but the `\cref` commands have an optional extra argument `UsedOn`.
When referencing a label via `\cref[UsedOn]{LABELNAME}` the following happens:

- `\AtBeginDocument` and `\ReadFromAux`:
  We read from the .aux file (see `\WriteToAux`) a key-value list, stored in the global proplist `\g_UsedOn_kv_prop`. For each key (`LABELNAME`) we create and set a counter `LastRun@LABELNAME` to the value (`max calls from last run`).
- `\cref` and `\Cref`:
  They call the original `cleveref` version and then call the custom `\crefUsedOnProcessor`.
- `\crefUsedOnProcessor`:
  If the optional argument `UsedOn` was passed to `\cref` then we loop through the `LABELNAME`s passed to `\cref` (which can receive a list of labelnames). For each `LABELNAME` we increase (or create and increase) the counter `ThisRun@UsedOn@LABELNAME`. If need be, update and store the counter `LastRun@UsedOn@LABELNAME` in `\g_UsedOn_kv_prop`. Then we create a new label `UsedOn@LABELNAME@NUMBER` with the original `\label` command where `NUMBER` is the current value of `ThisRun@UsedOn@LABELNAME` from the current run.
- `\label`:
  Calls the original `cleveref` version and then calls the custom `\PrintUsedOnLabel`.
- `\PrintUsedOnLabel`:
  If `LABELNAME` has been references with `UsedOn` option at least once then the refence `UsedOn@LABELNAME@1` exists. In this case we create a clist of parameters we want to pass to `\cpageref` to create our `Used on page...` phrase. We need `UsedOn@LABELNAME@1` to `UsedOn@LABELNAME@MAX` where `MAX` is the value of `LastRun@UsedOn@LABELNAME`.
- `\AtEndDocument` and `\WriteToAux`:
  We store the global proplist `\g_UsedOn_kv_prop` in the .aux file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}             %AMS theorems
\usepackage{mathtools}          %AMSmath++ facilities
\usepackage{thmtools}           %better theorem editing interface

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%=========================================
% -------- Exceptions to Hyperref (load last) ----------
%=========================================
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}   % needs to be loaded AFTER hyperref
                                    % because both update \label at the hook 
                                    % \AtBeginDocument and we want to use 
                                    % cleveref's \label
\crefname{page}{page}{pages}        % do NOT capitalise pages for more visual appeal
% This fixes the range bug for \cpageref in cleveref 0.21.4
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603514/267438
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@setcpagerefrange}[3]{%
    \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{cref}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\@setCpagerefrange}[3]{%
    \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{Cref}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\@setlabelcpagerefrange}[3]{%
    \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{labelcref}{#3}}
\makeatother

% declaretheorem needs to be executed AFTER loading cleveref 
% with the additional refname and Refname options
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498242/267438
% and the thmtools documentation
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section,
                name=Theorem,
                refname={Theorem,Theorems},
                Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem,
                name=Lemma,
                refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
                Refname={Lemma,Lemmas}]{lemma}

\usepackage{showlabels}     % to see the labels in the margin


%=========================================
% -------- BEGIN Overload label and cref ----------
%=========================================
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintUsedOnLabel}{ m }{%
    % Check if the reference `UsedOn@<LABELNAME>@1` exists
    % Here the @1 means that  <LABELNAME> has been referenced
    % with option `UsedOn` at least once
    \cs_if_exist:cT {r@UsedOn@#1@1}
    {   % Store in a tmp clist all the references of the form
        %   `UsedOn@<LABELNAME>@<NUMBER>` 
        % where NUMBER between 1 and \value{LastRun@UsedOn@<LABELNAME>}
        % if the latter exists, otherwise until 1
        % Should/will normally need two consecutive runs of pdflatex
        \cs_if_free:cTF {c@LastRun@UsedOn@#1}
            { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 1 } }
            { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \value{LastRun@UsedOn@#1} } }
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { 1 }
        \int_while_do:nn { \l_tmpb_int <= \l_tmpa_int } 
        {
            \clist_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { UsedOn@#1@\int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }
            \int_incr:N \l_tmpb_int
        }
        % Print `UsedOn` text by calling \cpageref with the parameter clist above
%           Arguments~of~cpageref~are:
%           \par\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\par}\par
        \emph{(Used~on~\cpageref{\l_tmpa_clist}.)}  \\%
    }
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\UsedOnProcessor}{ o m }{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {UsedOn}
        {   % Loop through (potential) label list in arg of \cref (or \Cref)
            \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
            \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 
            {   % if the label has not been referenced yet, 
                % create a counter and save the label in a global key sequence
                \seq_if_in:NxF \g_UsedOn_k_seq {UsedOn@##1}
                {
                    \newcounter{ThisRun@UsedOn@##1}
                    \cs_if_free:cT {c@LastRun@UsedOn@##1}
                        { \newcounter{LastRun@UsedOn@##1} }
                    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_UsedOn_k_seq {UsedOn@##1}
                }
                % increase the counter and compare with max counter
                \stepcounter{ThisRun@UsedOn@##1}
                \setcounter{LastRun@UsedOn@##1}{%
                    \fp_eval:n { max(%
                        \value{ThisRun@UsedOn@##1},%
                        \value{LastRun@UsedOn@##1} ) }%
                }
                % store the value in global key-value property list
                \prop_gput:Nxx \g_UsedOn_kv_prop 
                    {UsedOn@##1} {\arabic{LastRun@UsedOn@##1}}
                % create a label for the UsedOn reference and number this label
                \origlabel{UsedOn@##1@\arabic{ThisRun@UsedOn@##1}}
            }
        }
        {
            \msg_fatal:nn {UsedOn} 
                {Fatal~spelling~error~when~passing~option~`UsedOn`~to~cref~or~Cref}
        }
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\crefUsedOn}{ s o m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{ \origcref*{#3} }{ \origcref{#3} }%
    \UsedOnProcessor[#2]{#3}
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\CrefUsedOn}{ s o m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{ \origCref*{#3} }{ \origCref{#3} }%
    \UsedOnProcessor[#2]{#3}
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\ReadFromAux}{ }{%  
    % for each key create and set a counter
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_UsedOn_kv_prop
    {
        \newcounter{LastRun@##1}
        \setcounter{LastRun@##1}{##2}
    }
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\WriteToAux}{ }{%
    % Clear global key-value prop list \g_UsedOn_kv_prop
    % and rebuilt with info from current run
    \prop_clear:N \g_UsedOn_kv_prop
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_UsedOn_k_seq
        { \prop_gput:Nxx \g_UsedOn_kv_prop {##1}{\arabic{ThisRun@##1}} }
    % turn on expl3 functionality in aux file   
    \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
        { \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn }
    % loop through prop list and write to aux file
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_UsedOn_kv_prop
    {
        \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
            { \prop_gput_from_keyval:Nn \token_to_str:N \g_UsedOn_kv_prop {##1=##2} }
    }
    % turn off expl3 functionality in aux file  
    \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
        { \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff }
}%

% global key sequence \g_UsedOn_k_seq: 
%   container for `UsedOn` label names
\seq_new:N \g_UsedOn_k_seq
% global key-val prop list \g_UsedOn_kv_prop: 
%   container for `UsedOn` label names and their LastRunValue
\prop_new:N \g_UsedOn_kv_prop

%Read from .aux file and patch commands
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \ReadFromAux
    % Patch label and cref to include the new `UsedOn` capabilities
    \let\origlabel\label%
    \let\origcref\cref%
    \let\origCref\Cref%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{ m }{%
        \origlabel{#1}\PrintUsedOnLabel{#1}%
    }%
    \let\cref\crefUsedOn
    \let\Cref\CrefUsedOn
}%
% Write to .aux file
\AtEndDocument{%
    \WriteToAux
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
%=========================================
% -------- END Overload label and cref ----------
%=========================================
\begin{document}
\section{A new section}
\label{sec:TestSection}
Some text is written here.
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:TestTheorem}
The identity
\begin{equation*}
    1=1
\end{equation*}
is true.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma:TestLemma}
The identity
\begin{equation*}
    2=2.
\end{equation*}
is also true.
\end{lemma}

\subsection{A new subsection}

\par    The statements in \cref[UsedOn]{thm:TestTheorem} is true
and has been called with `UsedOn`. \\
\par    The statements in \cref[UsedOn]{lemma:TestLemma} is true
and has been called with `UsedOn`. \

\clearpage
.
\clearpage
.
\clearpage
\par    The statements in \cref[UsedOn]{thm:TestTheorem,lemma:TestLemma} are true
and have been called with `UsedOn`. \\

\clearpage
\par    \Cref[UsedOn]{thm:TestTheorem} is a true statement
and has been called with `UsedOn`. \\
\par    \Cref[UsedOn]{lemma:TestLemma} is a true statement
and has been called with `UsedOn`. \\

\clearpage
\par    \Cref[UsedOn]{thm:TestTheorem,lemma:TestLemma} are true statements
and have been called with `UsedOn`. \\

\subsection{Another subsection}
Here is yet another theorem.
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:TestTheoremSecond}
Content of theorem
\end{theorem}

The statement in \cref{thm:TestTheoremSecond} is also true 
but it has \emph{not} been called with `UsedOn`.

\subsection{Yet another subsection}
Printing counters. \\
Note that \emph{thm:TestTheoremSecond} does \emph{not} have a `UsedOn` counter.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{itemize}
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_UsedOn_kv_prop
    {
        \item The~value~of~the~counter~\emph{#1}~is~#2.
    }
\end{itemize}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```